# What hosting services can provide, supporting Ruby on Rails 3, can run a RabbitMQ server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rabbitmq

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am considering to implement [messaging queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) for my applications using the [Advanced Message Queuing Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) (AMQP).

So, relating to that arguments, I would like to know what hosting services can provide a [RabbitMQ server](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (this is an open source implementation of AMQP).

Comment: You want managed hosting? or virtual server like like ec2 works for you ?

Comment: Virtual server. I would to scale my applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like Amazon EC2 or Rackspace Cloud, you have full control of the systems then.